# Posts per Page not working

Tags: wp-query

I have custom post type of reviews, I want to limit the number of posts on the page, the standard methods do not work, please help!

```
<?php
   get_header();
   
   ?>
<div class="container category_reviews_inner">
   <main id="main" class="site-main clearfix">
      <div class="main-content" id="content">
         <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title page-title">Отзывы</h1>
         </header>
         <div class="entry-content">
            <div class="easy_testimonials_grid easy_testimonials_grid_1 easy_testimonials_grid_responsive">
               <?php
                  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                  
                       $args = array(
                           'post_type' => 'reviews',
                           
                           'order' => 'DESC',
                           'posts_per_page' => 6,
                           'paged' => $paged
                       );
                                     $arg_cat = array(
                                           'order'        => 'DESC',
                                           'hide_empty'   => 1,
                                           'exclude'      => '',
                                           'include'      => '',
                                           'taxonomy'     => 'reviews_Categories',
                                           'posts_per_page' => 6,
                                       );
                                       $categories = get_terms( $arg_cat );
                  foreach( $categories as $cat ){ $arg_posts =  array(
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                               'post_type' => 'reviews',
                                               'post_status' => 'publish',
                                               'posts_per_page' => 6,
                  
                                               'order'    => 'DESC',
                  
                                               'tax_query' => array(
                                                   array(
                                                       'taxonomy' => 'reviews_Categories',
                                                       'field'    => 'slug',
                                                       
                                                       'terms'    => $cat->slug,
                                                   )
                                               ),
                                           );}
                       $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                  
                   ?>
               <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?> 
               <!-- cemeteries -->
               <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
               <blockquote class="easy_testimonial for_title">
                  <div class="easy_testimonial_image_wrapper"></div>
                  <div class="testimonial_body">
                     <div class="review_title"><?= the_field('review_title') ?></div>
                  </div>
               </blockquote>
               <div class="easy_testimonials_grid_row easy_testimonials_grid_row_1">
                  <div class="easy_testimonials_grid_cell">
                     <div class="style-clean_style  show_thumbs show_title show_position hide_date stars_rating hide_other easy-t-category-kurs-magiya-schastya  easy_t_single_testimonial">
                        <blockquote class="easy_testimonial">
                           <div class="easy_testimonial_image_wrapper">
                              <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()): the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); else : ?>
                              <img width="400" height="400" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/imgs/user_icon.png" alt="Отзовик"/>
                              <?php endif ?>
                           </div>
                           <p class="testimonial_author">
                              <cite>
                              <span class="testimonial-client"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                              </cite>
                           </p>
                           <div class="testimonial_body">
                              <?php the_content(); ?>
                           </div>
                           <div style=""class="reviews_link">
                              <a href="/reviews-category/<?= $cat->slug ?>"
                                 class="easy_testimonial_title w-auto">&nbsp;
                              #<?= $cat->name ?></a>
                           </div>
                           <div class="easy_t_clear"></div>
                        </blockquote>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <?php endwhile; ?>
               <div class="col-md-12 options border-bottom">
                  <nav class="navigation posts-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Записи">
                     <!-- pagination -->
                     <div class="nav-links">
                        <?php
                           $total_pages = $the_query->max_num_pages;
                           if ($total_pages > 1){
                           
                            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
                           
                            echo paginate_links(array(
                                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                                'format' => '/page/%#%',
                                'current' => $current_page,
                                        'end_size'           => 1,
                             'mid_size'           => 2,
                                'total' => $total_pages,
                                'prev_text'    => __('← Предыдущие'),
                                'next_text'    => __('Новые →'),
                                'add_args'  => array()
                            ));
                           }
                            ?>
                     </div>
                  </nav>
               </div>
               <div class="all_categories">
                  <h2 class="entry-title page-title" style="text-align: center">Отзывы о курсе:</h2>
                  <?php
                     $term    = get_queried_object();
                     $term_id = ( isset( $term->term_id ) ) ? (int) $term->term_id : 0;
                     
                     $categories = get_categories( array(
                         'taxonomy'   => 'reviews_Categories',
                         'orderby'    => 'DESC',
                         'parent'     => 0,
                         'hide_empty' => 1,
                     ) );
                     ?>
                  <?php
                     foreach ( $categories as $category )
                     {
                         $cat_ID        = (int) $category->term_id;
                         $category_name = $category->name;
                     
                         $cat_class = ( $cat_ID == $term_id ) ? 'active' : 'not-active';
                     
                         if ( strtolower( $category_name ) != 'uncategorized' )
                         {?>
                  #<a href="/reviews-category/<?= $category->slug ?>" class="easy_testimonial_title w-auto"><?= $category->name ?>&nbsp;</a>
                  <?php  }
                     }
                     ?>
               </div>
               <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
               <?php else:  ?>
               <p>К сожалению отзывов нету</p>
               <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </main>
</div>
<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: You have nested loops, so  if your query shows 21 posts, and you have 5 categories, that's a loop of 21 posts displayed 5 times, aka 5 x 21 = 105 posts

Comment: The `get_terms()` function doesn't accept `posts_per_page` as an argument. See [WP_Term_Query::__construct()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for full arguments. For WP_Query you may want to try adding `suppress_filters` to make sure there's no hooks modifying your queries.

Comment: @tom-j-nowell Thank you more for your answers. Reworked the entire code, now pagination works. But there is a wrong post category under each post. Can you tell me what I did wrong? I updated the code in the first post.

Comment: You retrieved the categories once outside the loop then show the same categories over and over again, it's a basic logic error. It does not make sense to retrieve the current posts categories outside the loop, because outside the loop the current post is the page you're on, not the post in the loop. `$the_query->the_post()` changes the current post. You cannot retrieve each posts categories outside the loop the order you do things in matters

Comment: Can you fix your codes indenting and make sure that there isn't code bunched up on the same line? It's very difficult to follow and understand because of the formatting

Comment: I am completely new to programming, collecting everything in pieces from the Internet. I will try to understand what you wrote to me, thank you!